# How do I add spellcheck to a TextView object in my Quickly app?

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, quickly, spell-checking

Specifically for a Quickly app, using Gtk3:

1. How do you import GtkSpell in python?
2. How do you set it up to spell-check a TextView object?

(If there's an alternative to GtkSpell, do tell.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently: [no](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkspell/develop/).

The development of the C gtkspell3 seems to be stalled which would be required by the developers doing the python bindings before they can upgrade to support gtk3.

There is some evidence that you can use [python-aspell](http://0x80.pl/proj/aspell-python/), but it looks like you would have to recreate gtkspell from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

There is one using Enchant and works for PyGTK as well as for PyGObject.

Check: https://github.com/koehlma/pygtkspellcheck